# Getting no error message even after having validator in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I had created a collection named 'contacts' with following validation in mongodb 3.2

```
db.createCollection( "contacts",
   {
      validator: { $or:
         [
            { phone: { $type: "string" } },
            { email: { $regex: /@mongodb\.com$/ } },
            { status: { $in: [ "Unknown", "Incomplete" ] } }
         ]
      },
      validationAction: "error"
   }
)
```

After that I inserted below document:

```
db.contacts.insert( { name: "Girish Gupta", status: "Updated" } )
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

There should be some error as I am not inserting valid status.
But I am not getting any error.

Answer (score 0):

I met the very same problem today.

In fact, the doc just pointed out possible problems just below:

[Restrictions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document-validation/#restrictions) says:

> You cannot specify a validator for collections in the admin, local, and config databases.
>   You cannot specify a validator for system.* collections.

[Bypass Document Validation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document-validation/#bypass-document-validation):

> ... For deployments that have enabled access control, to bypass document validation, the authenticated user must have bypassDocumentValidation action. The built-in roles dbAdmin and restore provide this action.

So, if we use `admin` to operate, it will surely `bypass` the validation. Just add a new user (not admin) and perform the operations will get expected answer.